# Changing table cell background color

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have searched around and seen various answers but have yet to solve my problem here. I am trying to set my UITableViewCell background color to something other than white. I have

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.949 green:0.949 blue:0.949 alpha:1.0];
```

But this does not change the background color of the accesoryView where I currently the disclosure indicator. I have tried:

```
cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.949 green:0.949 blue:0.949 alpha:1.0];
```

to no avail. I have also tried setting this as clear and messing with the other background colors. What am I missing here? This seems to be an easy fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that could not have been any easier...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.949 green:0.949 blue:0.949 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Rookie mistake, apparently.